# Running a function on a successful ping command in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, ping

Tell me how to organize the function after executing the ping command and receiving a response? If the answer is not received (the function is not executed), then we wait 2 minutes and again run the ping command.

```
from tkinter import *

def test():
        try:

        except:
            pass

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to ping like this, but with ping 192.168.1.1 (existing address) - ping successful, 192.168.1.2 (nonexistent address) - ping successful, 192.168.2.1 (nonexistent address) - ping unsuccessful.

```
import os
hostname = "192.168.1.1"
response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
  print ('is up!')
else:
  print ('is down!')
```

Comment: If you are in the position I would take a look at the more modern subprocess package. It will be easier to extract this information from the API that package provides.

Comment: try using [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `os.system()`